# Custom attribute in customer order conformation mail

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

How to call Custom attribute in customer order conformation mail

i try lot of solution but no luck Please give me some solution on that

Comment: Share what your code looks like now and what have you tried so far, to start understanding where you are having issues

Comment: I follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393479/add-custom-attribute-in-order-email-templates-magento?rq=1 but i don't know how to include custom attribut

Comment: You'd have to show what how you  are calling the function and ylur email template file

Comment: Actually i don't know how to add order.php in custom attribute

Comment: Sorry but you are not giving enough information to be able to help you